# How to install oracle APEX 20.1 with oracle database 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I want to install oracle apex 20.1 with oracle database 10g.I search google and it seems like oracle apex not supported on oracle database 10g

Answer (score 3):

As you've already noticed, that won't work.

If you want to install Apex on 10g, that would probably be Apex 4.0 (as its minimum supported database version is 10.2.0.3).

Apex 20.1 requires at least 11.2.0.4.

Therefore:

- upgrade the database (10g is really old; I'd consider that option first), or
- install lower (*much* lower) Apex version if you manage to acquire it as - currently - the lowest Apex version available for download is Apex 5.0 which requires database 11.1.0.7.

Basically, you're pretty much out of luck with your database version ...